# Optimal SQL query for querying 31 tables (containing datestamp in tablename)

Tags: sql

Fairly new to SQL and I was stumped on this question I received in an interview recently.

The question was along the lines of how would you count the total occurrences of 'True' for Column B in July.

Problem was; there was no date or timestamp column in the table. Instead the table naming convention was defined as "ProductX_YYYYMMDD". The assumption being that a new table is created for each day's data dump.

Is there an efficient query I can write to obtain the True COUNTs of Column B for each table (which doesn't involve ~30 JOIN or UNION statements to get the answer)?

Comment: As this will require dynamic SQL, the answer will be product specific. I don't think this can be done with "plain" standard SQL. So which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name On point. This is heavily database specific, not a generic SQL question.

Comment: Ok, it was for an interview so specific product is undefined. Not sure I want to waste your time with a hypothetical (so feel free to tell me to suck eggs!) but if it was mysql or postgres how would you do it? You know what - let me look more into dynamic SQL as this has identified a gap in my knowledge, you've already given some good direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use `STRING_SPLIT(myColumn, '_')` 
Then

```
SELECT RIGHT (SELECT LEFT(tempColumn, -4)), -2)
```

Now you have a temp table filled with only month |MM| and you can use

```
COUNT() FROM dailyTable WHERE dailyName like '07'
```

Add the count of every daily Table to a variable

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. The intent was to run the query across all tables at once rather than add to a new variable or create new table.

Comment: Another way you could permanently solve this issue is using a view and triggers, but all of that requires creating new tables and/or using joins